# Display Public groups & its associated users after selecting Group in drop down list in visualforce page?

Tags: apex, visualforce, public-group

Display `Public Groups` in drop down list & in this list select one public group, then press search button, on pressing search button display the all users in particular public group.

Answer (score 2):

To display Public groups in drop down list and in `Available Public Groups` list select one public group,then press `List Users` button. After pressing the  `List Users` button, you will get the all `Available Users` associated with that groups as shown in below screen shot as well.

**Output:** 
 [image]

**Code:**

**Visualforce Page Code**

```
<apex:page controller="GroupsController" >
    <br/>
    <div style="padding:30px;">
        <apex:form >
            <div style="text-align:center;">
                <b style="padding-bottom:15px;">Available Public Groups</b>
                <br/>
                <apex:selectList value="{!selectedVal}" size="10" style="width:305px;">
                    <apex:selectOptions value="{!groupsList}"/>
                </apex:selectList>
            </div>
            <br/>
            <center><apex:commandButton action="{!setmyValue}" reRender="textDisplay" value="List Users"/></center>
            <br/>
            <div style="text-align:center;">
                <b style="padding-bottom:15px;">Available Users</b>
                <br/>
                <apex:outputPanel id="textDisplay">
                    <apex:selectList value="{!selectedVal1}"  size="10" style="width:305px;">
                        <apex:selectOptions value="{!users_id}"/>
                    </apex:selectList>
                </apex:outputPanel>
            </div>
        </apex:form>
    </div>  
</apex:page>
```

**Apex Code**

```
public class GroupsController {
    public String selectedVal{
        get{return selectedVal;}set{selectedVal= value;}
    }
    public String selectedVal1{
    get;set;
    }
    public List<SelectOption> users_id {
         get{return users_id;}
         set{users_id=value;}
    }
    public PageReference setmyValue(){
         List<GroupMember> gm = [SELECT userorgroupid from GroupMember where groupid=:selectedVal];  
         List<String> group_id  = new  List<String>();
         for(GroupMember g:gm){
              group_id.add(g.userorgroupid+'');
         }
         List<USER> users_1  = [SELECT name from User where id in :group_id];
         users_id = new List<SelectOption>();
          for(User u:users_1 ){
              users_id.add(new SelectOption(u.name,u.name));
         }
        return null;
    }
    public List<selectOption> getGroupsList(){        
            SET<String> fields = new SET<String>();
                        fields = Schema.SObjectType.Group.fields.getmap().keyset();
                        System.debug(fields);
                        List<Group> groups = [select developername,name, type from group where type= 'Regular'];
                        Map<id,Group> group_maps = new Map<id,Group>();
                        List<selectOption> g1roupsList = new List<selectOption>();
            for(Group g :groups){
                        group_maps.put(g.id,g);
                g1roupsList.add(new SelectOption(g.id,g.developername));
                        }
                        System.debug(group_maps);
            return g1roupsList;
    }
}
```

Try the code and do practice. Thanks!!